# Trying to sort listbox by clicking button, without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, listbox

I am working on a listbox that has items added by the user. I figured out how to delete items, but after a few hours of trying I am unable to sort alphabetically.

Comment: hey, can you paste the code of the `PairListBox` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can do it that way:

```
var $listbox = document.getElementById('PairListBox');
var $options = $listbox.find('option');
$options.sort(function(a,b){
  var an = a.textContent.toLowerCase(),
    bn = b.textContent.toLowerCase();

  if(an > bn) {
    return 1;
  }
  if(an < bn) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

$options.detach().appendTo($listbox);
```

EDIT:

Without jQuery (probably you can do better):

```
var $options = [].map.call($listbox.children, function(option) { return option });;
$options.sort(function(a,b){
  a = a.textContent.toLowerCase();
  b = b.textContent.toLowerCase();

  if(a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  if(a < b) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
$options.forEach(function($option) {
  $listbox.remove($option);
});
$options.forEach(function($option) {
  $listbox.appendChild($option);
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that. Unfortunately I'm not using jQuery. Is there a way to sort the listbox without it?

Comment: I tried your code and @RobG 's.. For some reason in CodePen I can get the items to Add + Delete, but not sort: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYKbxg ...In jsFiddle, I can't get the items to perform any of the functions: http://jsfiddle.net/4frmq840/3/  ..any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
function SortList(listname) { 
    var $r = $(listname + " option"); 
    $r.sort(function(a, b) { 
        return (a.value < b.value) ? -1 : (a.value > b.value) ? 1 : 0;
        //or you can have a.text, b.text, etc
    }); 
    $($r).remove(); 
    $(listname).append($($r)); 
} 

$('#sort').click(function(e) { SortList('#listbox'); });
```

From http://jsfiddle.net/Kz2bg/19/

Answer (score 0):

The following will do the job in plain JS. It puts the options into an array, sorts that, then re–orders the select. You can make the sort function anything you like, this uses a simple numeric sort.

```
<script>

// Sort options of a select element by value
function sortSelectByValue(select) {
  var arr = toArray(select.options);
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {return a.value - b.value});
  arr.forEach(function(opt) {
    select.appendChild(opt);
  })

  // Optional - set first option as selected
  select.selectedIndex = 0;
}

// Convert a list like object to an Array
function toArray(obj) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=0, iLen=obj.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (i in obj) {
      arr[i] = obj[i];
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
</script>
```

Some play markup:

```
<select id="sel0">
  <option value="2">2
  <option value="0">0
  <option value="1">1
</select>

<input type="button" value="sort select" onclick="
  sortSelectByValue(document.getElementById('sel0'));
">
```

If you want to live on the edge, the following works in modern browsers:

```
// Sort options of a select element by value
function sortSelectByValue(select) {
  var arr = Array.prototype.splice.call(select.options, 0, select.options.length)
                 .sort(function(a, b) {return a.value - b.value})
                 .forEach(function(opt) {select.appendChild(opt)});
}
```

#### Edit

BTW, in your original function, the following:

```
var newOption = document.createElement('option');
newOption.value = textbox.value; // The value that this option will have
newOption.innerHTML = textbox.value; // The displayed text inside of the <option> tags
```

can be:

```
var newOption = new Option(textbox.value, textbox.value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here is a link to my code, I still can't get it to sort: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYKbxg

Comment: Changing your *sortByName* button to use the above sort function works fine.

Comment: Okay thanks alot for your help, I'm going to have to go over it again to learn my mistakes

Comment: Within *sortItems*, *$listbox* was undefined. It's much better if you post code here.